# How to view orphans in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing

Assume someone shares a folder with me, he remains the owner of the folder. Then I put some (many) files into this folder, of which I am and remain the owner. Then that someone revokes my access to said folder.

Now, where can I access these files in a useful way? I know that I can still access the file from the "Quota" list, but only the large ones can be accessed in a useful way, the smaller ones are somewhere much further down and mixed into all other files.

Comment: Oh funny, once I typed this questions, googling for drive orphans gives some answers that I hadn't found before: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6008339
However, it does not answer my question, because none of these options gives me only the orphans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://support.google.com/a/answer/6008339?hl=en states that a search in Drive for `is:unorganized owner:me` returns orphaned items that you own. Note that it returns the top-level folder if a folder hierarchy has been orphaned.

From there you can use `Move...` to add item *en masse* to your own Drive.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Some parts of this answer are now obsolete as [Find your files - Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/1716222?hl=en) was updated recently. This was noted thanks to the [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/87473/88163) by [Dean Ransevycz](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/109743/dean-ransevycz)

---

At this time Google Drive doesn't include a view nor a search operator to find only orphaned files. From [1]:

> **To find an orphaned item, do one of the following:**
>
> - [Search for the item](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114) in the search box at the top of Google Drive on the web.
> - If you own the orphaned item, you can get a list of everything you own and look for the item in that list. Click the down arrow in the
>     Google Drive search box and select **Ownership > Owned by me**.
> - If you've accessed the file recently, click **Recent** in the left navigation and then browse for the file.
> - To browse everything in Google Drive on the web, click **More** in the left navigation, and then click **All Items** (Classic Google Drive only).
>
> Once you find the orphaned file, you'll probably want to move it into
>   My Drive (or another folder), to give it a home and make it easier to
>   find in the future.

From [2]

> ... you can extend the capabilities of documents, spreadsheets, and forms
>   by adding custom menus, dialogs, and sidebars with [Google Apps
>   Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)

Assume that you want to automatically move the Orphaned files to a folder in "My Drive" named `Orphaned`

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27957068/1595451

```
 function collectOrphans(findOrphaned) {
   var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Orphaned').next();
   var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
   var orphanCount = 0;
   while(files.hasNext()){
      var file = files.next();
      if(!file.getParents().hasNext()){
        folder.addFile(file);
        orphanCount++;      
      }
    }
   Logger.log('Moved ' + orphanCount + ' orphans successfully.');
}
```

**Remarks**

- The above code could exceed the processing time limit, so could be necessary to call it several times. The Continuous Batch Library ([3]) could be useful for dealing with this.
- Folders also could be orphans, the above code only works for files but could be used as a base for collecting orphan folders.

**References**
1 [Find your files - Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/1716222?hl=en)
2 [Extend Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms with Apps Script - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)
3 [Continous Batch Libray UPDATE for Google Apps Script](http://patt0.blogspot.com/2014/08/continuous-batch-library-update-for.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I think this quote appears exactly on the page I am referring to in my comment to my question.

Comment: @bers: Comments are not the best place for the author of question to add relevant information about his own question. Instead edit the question. To learn more a bout comments, please read http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment.