# Deleting old/unwanted files

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing

If I no longer in need of a shared document that I do not own, can I delete it without bothering anyone else’s (owners included)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I delete a shared file from Google Drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/55274/how-can-i-delete-a-shared-file-from-google-drive)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the shared files with you from "My Drive". Be careful to not remove them from folders shared with you as editor because you could remove files from the folder for all.

Related

- [Does deleting a file from Incoming folder in Google Drive delete the original file?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/78629/88163)
- [What's an efficient way to delete shared Google Drive files?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/85027/88163)

Comment: @ahorn It used to be called "My Unit"