# Google Drive "quota" path: where are those files?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-shared-folder, google-drive-folder

Google tells me that my quota is exceeded and clicking on the suggested link "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/quota" I can see a lot of files, many of them of large size, but they aren't on my drive.

I can't see where they are located, they are not in "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/my-drive" nor "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/shared-with-me".

Isn't weird? Where are these files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to view orphans in Google Drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/74793/how-to-view-orphans-in-google-drive)

Comment: Also look at the Google Drive Trash/Bin and if have made a backup of a device on the corresponding "drive". If you want to see on a one by one, open the file information/activity  panel.

Comment: @Rubén Seems not to be the same problem. Searching for `is:unorganized owner:me` give me other files more! I'm getting crazy!
I have no files in the trash and no backups coming from other devices :(

Answer (score 2):

You can find the location of a item in the Quota screen by clicking on it, then looking at the bottom of the screen to see the folder path, or alternatively by opening the info panel on the right-hand side, then looking at the folder where it says "Location". (See the orange circles in the screenshot below.)

If these are empty, you have an 'orphaned' file, which means it does not belong in any folder, but it still takes up storage space.

[image: Finding the location of items in the Quota screen]

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I have few files that seems to be orphaned, because they don't have any parent folder and I can't see them on my drive. Other files instead have a parent folder, but I cannot see it anyway! I can enter it but if I start from root folder of my drive that folder doesn't exist. So, could they be orphaned folders?

Comment: You need to click on the three dots to expand the folder path, and see the full path.

Comment: I can't see any full path. Anyway if I click on the parent folder of a file it goes to a search query! For example I have a file and I see its parent folder is "Video". If I click on it, it leads me to "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/search?q=Video" O_o. It seems that folder doesn't exist...

Comment: Please contact Google support, and share your screen with them so that they can understand what is wrong.

Comment: How can I contact the Google Drive support?

Comment: There's a question mark on the top right of the screen. Support is only available for Google One members (those who pay for storage).

Comment: So, it is not my case. Thank you anyway.