# Missing files after restoring suspended G Suite account

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace-for-business

My organization uses G Suite. One of our accounts is used mainly as a storage account (some emails are forwarded to it, and its Google Drive is used for storing files which are later on shared with other members of my organization).

Due to the pandemic, some my our coworkers have left the organization, and their accounts were suspended by the administrator. Among those, our storage account was accidentally suspended as well (none of us noticed, due to reduced business operations).

Now the coworkers are back, their accounts are active once again, and the storage account is active as well. However, the files are nowhere to be found in that account's Google Drive. I'm sure that the files still exist, because they are accessible via the old shared links, they're just invisible in Google Drive.

Searching for them by name, and with various search operators (from:worker1@myorganization.org, to:..., etc), yields no results.

Searching with: `is:unorganized owner:me`, `is:unorganized`, or just `owner:me` also yields no results.

Comment: Have you already read [How to view orphans in Google Drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/74793/88163)?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Thank you, I'll give it a go, and see if it solves my problem. If not, I'll expand my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in multiple remembered logins on the browsers used to check for the missing Google Drive files. Both of the browsers were constantly opening the same (unwanted) account.