# File not showing on "Shared with me", even with a Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive

I noticed I have a file (propably more) that I can find it by searching, and it tells me its in the **Shared with me** location, but when I go to the **Shared with me** the file is not there.

[image]

I tried using a Apps Script and the file is found when searching by its name

```
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "NameOfTheFile"');
```

But is not found when searching like this

```
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "NameOfTheFile" and SharedWithMe = true');
```

I'm the owner of the file, so i'm not sure why the file is listed in the **Shared with me** location, and I think that is the main problem, because the file probably isn't really shared with me.

But if that's the case how can I get the list of all files that are on the **Shared with me** location but are not really shared with me?

Comment: To be clear, Apps script is not offtopic on SO.  However, your question is not about apps script itself, but about  Google drive user interface, which is appropriate here.

Comment: Well, I think it envolves both. I posted Apps Script code and what happened when using Apps Script. What should I do? Post on boths? EDIT: I Undeleted on SO. Kind of new using SO when asking questions.

Comment: How "it tells" you that the file is in **Shared with me**?

Comment: By the way, using Google Drive terminology, files that you own aren't shared with you, in other words you can't share files owned by account A with account A. Do you have more than one account using the same name?

Comment: I understand that, that's I think thats the reason that file is not showing when I click the Shared With Me and using SharedWithMe = true on the Apps Script. Added image to the post to show the file on the Shared With Me location.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. What is the source of the image? Recents, Starred,...?  Please also add an image of the file details (right click the file and select "View Details"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely that "Shared with me" is the default value for files that aren't located in My Drive , Shared Drive or folder within them. Perhaps your file is an orphaned file. Just move the file to My Drive a Shared Drive or a folder.

Related

- [How to view orphans in Google Drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/74793/88163)

Comment: Thats it! Thank you very much!